# JSP - How to use EL session.attr?

Tags: java, jsp, session, el

I want to get values from `HttpSession` object, using EL.

```
    <body>
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("timLim", 50);
    <script>
    var min="${session.timLim}";
    alert(min); //Getting no output
    </script>
    </body>
```

How to assign value of `min` back to `timLim` using EL `session.timLim` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use it without session:

```
var min="${timLim}";
```

Comment: How to assign min back to timLim?

Comment: Possible clarification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590620/are-session-and-sessionscope-the-same-in-jsp-el